# regex digit empty string

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a question about regular expression evaluation. Here is some java code that tests for only digits in a string:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class RegexPractice
{
    public RegexPractice()
    {
    }

    public static void checkNum(String pattern)
    {
        if(pattern.matches("^\\d*"))
        {
            System.out.println(pattern);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("false");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        checkNum("543853473");
        checkNum("ipabgrieahgbre");
        checkNum("frgwe9789fdsa798dfas");
        checkNum("54336534 4364 546 654");
        checkNum("");
        checkNum(" ");
    }

}
```

if the passed string matches the regex "^\d" then print the string otherwise print false. I was surprised to see that the empty string was printed. Why is this so? because it doesn't contain a digit.

I am aware that I can solve this by not allowing empty strings but I am curious as to why it has been been evaluated as true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of regex: `\\d*`

which means match 0 or more digits hence empty string also mathes.

Make it:

```
pattern.matches("^\\d+$")
```

to avoid matching empty string and to make sure ONLY digits are matched in input.

[**Recommended Reading on RegEx**](http://regular-expressions.info)

Comment: I see, I should have read more carefully. Could also achieve the same by evaluating against: "^\\d\\S*" ?

Comment: `^\\d\\S*` will match a single digits followed by 0 or more non-space characters. So it will match `1` OR `100` OR `5%` etc